# PHP echo days since certain date to todays date

Tags: php, date, counter, datediff

I'm trying to print the number of days that have passed since a certain date in the past, based on the current date. if I use date_create("2016-12-09") for my date2 it will work. How can I set date2 to dynamically be todays date? I tried the below but it errors..

```
        <?php
           $date1=date_create("2012-01-06");
           $date2=date('o-m-d');
           $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
           $road = $diff->format("%a");
        ?>
```

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/date it returns a **STRING**, not a datetime object.

Comment: to fix this, `new DateTime` defaults to now.